# C++ Use std::map.count with array as key of map

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, dictionary

I have created a map where a byte array is used as the key, and the frequency of occurrences of the given array is used as the value. I have to do it without using the Qt framework.

In Qt, this code works:

```
if (!mapa.count(byteArray)) mapa.insert(byteArray, 1);
else mapa[byteArray]++;
```

But my code doesn't work.

```
byte byteArray[16];
map<byte(*)[16], int> mapa;
if (!mapa.count(&byteArray)) {
    mapa.insert(pair<byte(*)[16], int>(&byteArray, 1));
}
else {
    mapa[&byteArray]++;
}
```

In my case, the program uses the address of the array, not its data.

Comment: If you use a pointer as a key, then it's the actual *pointer* that is the real key. If you have two different pointer to otherwise identical data, then they will still be different elements because the pointers are different.

Comment: On another note, you don't need to check for the existence of a key in a map before using it. The `[]` operator of `std::map` will insert an element (with default/zero initialized data) if the key doesn't already exist in the map. So for your example code you don't need either the `count` or the `insert` calls, all you need is `mapa[&byteArray]++`.

Comment: I also suggest you use `std::unordered_map` instead, since what seems like your use-case you don't need the map to be ordered on the key.

Comment: Arrays are not first class types in C++. Suggest you use `std::array` instead `map<array<byte,16>, int>`

Comment: OP what @Someprogrammerdude describes is a good use case for operator[], in most other code the automatic insert (of key, default values) is likely a source of bugs. And insert(key,value), and at(key) should be used. And I agree with John, use std::array in C++

Comment: @john I tried to use std::array, but my program wasn't even compiled.

Comment: @keepky In that case, please ask a new question, showing your new code.  No 'mission creep' please.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude without a pointer I can't use array. std::pair doesn't work with it

Comment: @keepky [Works fine for me](https://godbolt.org/z/nb1M8xaqP). You're probably doing something you shouldn't be doing.

Comment: @keepky In that case you need to post the code that doesn't compile. From your description using `std::array` seemed like the simplest solution, so don't give up just because you can't get it to compile. Show the code you are having trouble with.

Answer (score -1):

When you create an array like this: `byte arr[16]`, you actually create 16 bytes in the RAM and store them one next to the other.

Because of that, the name of the array is actually a pointer to the array's first element, because a pointer to the first element will actually point to the start of the array.

So, if you create a map where the key is like this `byte(*) [16]`, you are not referring to an array of bytes, but to an array of pointers (which can also be an array of array's - two dimensional array) .

So when you create a map, you need to write `byte*` to refer to a byte pointer.

```
byte byteArray[16];
std::map<byte*, int> mapa;

if(maps.count(byteArray) == 0)
   //do something
else
   //do something else
```

Comment: Seems like it works. Can you help me with output array from map?

Comment: This method refers to a pointer, but I need to refer to the bytes of array

Comment: @keepky It's impossible to help unless you post the code you have tried. Then we can see what you did wrong.